# Arrayfire vs OpenCV performance

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gpu, arrayfire

I'm developing a "performance critical" image processing program on a `Jetson TX1` device, and until this time I used `OpenCV`, but now I decided to switch to `Arrayfire` for some speedup. However, it seems to be much slower now.

Basically, I had two options:

- Forget `OpenCV` completely, and use the `Arrayfire` image processing functions.
- Use a conversion between `cv::Mat` and `af::array` at the critical parts.

The problem is that my original `OpenCV` implementation of the key function which does the job runs in ~160ms, while only the conversion itself takes ~110ms.

And there are other other unpleasant functions like `medianBlur`, which takes at most 60 ms on CPU with `OpenCV`, and ~250 ms with `Arrayfire` on GPU. (I know that `medianBlur` is not ideal for GPU-s, but 5 times slower code is quite embarrassing for my application, and doing only that part with `OpenCV` leads to problem again since conversion is too slow between `cv::Mat` and `af::array`. I can't possibly implement faster `medianBlur` on CPU than the existing one in `OpenCV`)

So what can I do now?

Comment: you can't always stick together libraries and call it a day. Especially in performance critical code you sometimes just need to write it yourself. As for how exactly you find out why things take so long, use a profiler to find your bottlenecks

Comment: Hi Zerge, The time for 5x5 median filter on GPU of ArrayFire you reported doesn't sound right. How are you timing ArrayFire ? Please be sure to read http://arrayfire.org/docs/timing.htm article before you go ahead and time any arrayfire code if you haven't already. First call to any function in ArrayFire does incur warm-up cost, so please make sure you are averaging that out or excluding that.

What image sizes are you testing on ?
Which GPU backend are you using ? CUDA/OpenCL

- Pradeep.

Comment: Warm-up times were the problem I did not realize, thanks!

Comment: Hi @zerge. You conclude that warm-up times were the problem. But, what's your final conclusion? I'm starting to switch to ArrayFire. Should I desist?